# Android NestedScrollView fillViewport stretching incorrectly

Tags: android, android-support-library, android-design-library

I am trying to use the new `NestedScrollView` from the support libraries. I want the scrollable content to expand to match parent if it is smaller. I see that to do that, I'm supposed to add `fillViewport=true` to the `NestedScrollView`. When I do this, my scrollable content doesn't stretch vertically, it instead stretches horizontally off-screen. [image]

The layout card_movie simply has a `RelativeLayout` with some TextViews and one `ImageView` inside it. Nothing special. [image]

Answer (score 16):

I have used it like this:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
        android:fillViewport="true">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical" 
            ...
```

Maybe the difference is that the linear layout has a specified orientation or maybe I am using a more updated library `com.android.support:design:23.1.0` and that is the reason why I cant reproduce your problem.

Comment: Boom! That's what I'm talking about!

Answer (score 3):

Maybe I am too late for this, but the way I solved this was to replace `NestedScrollView` child (in your case, `RelativeLayout`) `margin` with `padding`. If that didn't work, also try replacing `RelativeLayout` child `margin` with `padding`.

Let me know if that works!