# ConstraintLayout not filling whole screen

Tags: android, android-constraintlayout, android-nestedscrollview

I have `ConstraintLayout` inside the `NestedScrollView`.
If I don't use `NestedScrollView` to wrap `ConstraintLayout` then the `ConstraintLayout` takes whole screen area, but as soon as I wrap it with `NestedScrollView`, the `ConstraintLayout` wraps its views and takes only the wrapped space.

But, I need `ConstraintLayout` to stay with its parent `NestedScrollView` or at least screen height.

For me, I have inflated fragments in the `ViewPager2`. When `ConstraintLayout` wraps its content views, I am not able to see fragment in `ViewPager2` in runtime.

If I remove `NestedScrollView`, everything works perfectly and I am able to see all fragment correctly.

Here is my layout code.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:padding="16dp">
    
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:text="Sample Text"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"/>
    
    <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tabLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:tabGravity="fill"
        android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/textView">
        
        <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabItem
            android:id="@+id/first"
            android:text="First"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
        <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabItem
            android:id="@+id/second"
            android:text="Second"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
        <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabItem
            android:id="@+id/third"
            android:text="Third"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
    </com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout>
    
    <androidx.viewpager2.widget.ViewPager2
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/tabLayout"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"/>
    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
</androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

I have some images included.

[image]
[image]
[image]

Any help will be appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Android NestedScrollView fillViewport stretching incorrectly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32065850/android-nestedscrollview-fillviewport-stretching-incorrectly)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`android:fillViewport="true"` helped to inflate the fragment, means I was able to see the fragments at run time. But, fragments had different heights. So, another problem created as ViewPager allocated same height for all the fragments.

Finally, on each fragment's `onResume` method, I need to call `requestLayout()`.
And that solved problem of different heights of fragment.

```
override fun onResume() {
   super.onResume()
   binding.root.requestLayout()
}
```

Link to the answer: [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64897784/9184497)